# How to draw ER diagram for recursive relation when the number of roles is more than 3?

Tags: oracle, database-design, recursive

I know for a recursive relation where there are 2 roles, for example:
**Worker works for Manager**
and **Worker and Manager both are 2 roles of Employee**, we show it this way:

[image]

But what if Employee had roles like:
1. Director
2. Manager
3. Secretary
4. Worker
and every role in the lower hierarchy works for the ones in the higher rank.

For Example:
**Manager** **works for Director**, **Secretary works for Director** and,   **Worker Works for Director**

Then again,
**Secretary and Worker also Works for Manager** and so on...

How to show that in the ER DIAGRAM?

Comment: Re-adjust your thinking.  Roles don't report to roles.  People report to people.  The role is just an attribute of a particular person.  Focus on the people, not the role.

Comment: @EdStevens I would suggest the opposite is true. Most organisation charts are concerned with roles and how one role relates to another. That way there is continuity in structure and duties even as individuals come and go.

Comment: @MichaelGreen - Jane is in the role of Admin Assistant.  Today she works for Joe, who is in the role of Supervisor.  Tomorrow she gets transferred to work for Phil, a VP.  She is still an Admin Assistant.  I've never seen a database that tracks org charts, but I've seen plenty that track people.

Comment: True. And tomorrow Joe will have an open position for an Admin Assistant, which HR will start the process of filling, and yesterday Phil had a role, reporting to him, with no person in it. The positions still exist, absent the people, with the same reporting structure. Had Jane become Phil's PA instead of Admin Assistant should we have deleted the old "Jane" record and created a new? No, because the people and the positions each have continuity even as the links between them change.

Answer (score 2):

Organisations are generally far more flexible than we initially think.
For example, Jon might have two jobs in the organisation (Developer and Acting Team Lead).

He may report to Bill the Development Manager for his Acting Team lead role and to Bob for the Development work that he still carries out.

This necessitates having the self referencing relationship for REPORTS_TO expand out into another entity type so that each person can report to many others rather than just one.
You also need to be able to show that each person can have many roles/jobs and the you may want to have some roles that officially report to multiple roles.

[image]

From another perspective hierarchies like this are worth exploring in a graph database as that is what they excel at. Not having a formal schema also means that they are very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different things we need to store information about. First is the positions within the corporate organisation. Second is the reporting structure between these positions. Third is the people who currently fill each position.

While it is possible to design a database that holds all this in a single table, especially with the very limited cases in the question, I believe that would not be proper to do so. Take salary as an example. Most jobs have a salary *range* or pay grade. An individual person, however, will have a specific number (which lies within the position's range). That number is functionally dependent on the person, not the position, and so should be normalized into a separate entity type. It is clear, too, that tax details and next-of-kin details will follow a person if she changes position and do not relate to what she happens to be doing right now.

Conversely it is quite usual for a new position to enter (or leave) the org chart some time before a person fills it (or is made redundant). It is here, in the position, that the roles you list in the question are stored. Position 1729, say, could have the title "widget fixer" and role "worker."

Similarly with the reporting hierarchy. The information required to define the relationship is the senior and junior position IDs - the Team Leader reports to the Manager, the Secretary is under the Director. This makes it different to either of the others and its own entity type.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create two entities 'Job' and 'Employee'for that purpose.
[image]

Relational Schema
Employee(**Employee_ID**, Name)
Job(**Job_ID**, Job_Title,Salary)
Join(**Works_For**, **Job_ID**)

You can provide these roles through 'Job_Title'.
You can learn more from sample schemas(Like HR similar to your requirement) provided by Oracle.
[Schema Diagrams](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/diagrams.htm#COMSC00016)

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "role" though. It's an Oracle keyword (and in other systems), so the table name "Job" would be better. This is simply addressed as a tree - look up hierarchies and trees - a CEO is boss to the VPs who are bosses to managers who are bosses to supervisors to shop floor workers (you can have **any** number of levels). The HR schema in Oracle covers this - Google HR schema, trees and hierarchy and you should have plenty to going along with.